# SQL Server INSTALLATION FAILED

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to install SQL Server 2019 on my laptop (Windows 11). But the installation failed with the following exceptions:

[image]

Comment: If you're trying to install 2019, why do your tags say 2012? The logs also suggest 2012. I doubt 2012 runs on Windows 11.

Comment: Quite frankly, don't use Windows 11 generally. It is just too new and many people have problems installing on that OS.

Answer (score 2):

As @Larnu suggests it looks like you are installing 2012 and you are running into a compatibility issue. The [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/general/use-sql-server-in-windows) specifically states that SQL Server 2012 is not supported on Windows 11.

[image]